# Check if array elements are in prompt value, then do something

Tags: javascript

I want to create a javaScript program which demands a number. If the number contains an even number,  the number would then be displayed without the even number

Please forgive the code, it may seem dumb, I'm still trying to understand javascript..

I've tried this though

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userInput = prompt("choose an even number");

var evenNumbers = [2,6,4,8,10];

for ( x=0; x<evenNumbers.length; x++) {
    userInput -= evenNumbers[x];

    document.write( userInput );
}
</script>
```

Comment: What would be the desired input (`userInput`) and what would be the desired outcome? Because currently the meaning of your script confuses me.

Comment: The user inputs any number at all....if it contains an eve number in the array, I want the input to be displayed without the even number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve but I suppouse two possible desired results:

First:

If **user introduces** a number like: **123456**

**You want to display** the same string without the even numbers like: **135**

If that's correct my answer is:

```
var userResult = new Array();
var userInput = prompt("choose an even number");

//Split the string to have every number independent
var number = userInput.split("");
//For every number
for (var x=0; x<number.length; x++) {
    //Check if it's a odd number (so it's not a even number)
    if( (number[x] % 2) != 0){
        //Push the number to the result
        userResult.push(number[x]);
    }
}
//Re-format the result to have it as a string without commas
document.write(userResult.join(""));
```

Second:

If **user introduces** a number like: **4**

**You want to display** you even numbers array without the number (if even): **2,6,8,10**

If that's correct my answer is:

```
var userInput = prompt("choose an even number");
var evenNumbers = [2, 6, 4, 8, 10];


//Check if it's a even number
if( (userInput % 2) == 0){
    //If it is, find where is this number on your evenNumbers array...
    for (var x=0; x<evenNumbers.length; x++) {
        //..and remove it from the array
        if(userInput == evenNumbers[x]){
            evenNumbers.splice(x, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
document.write(evenNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#filter` to exclude a specific value in an array of values.

```js
// var userInput = prompt("choose an even number");
var userInput = '3456789'

function excludeEvenNumber(x) {
  return x.split('') // split the numbers on each character
    .filter(function(y) { return Number(y) % 2 !== 0 }) // filter out even numbers
    .join('') // join the character array into a string
}

console.log(
  excludeEvenNumber(userInput)
)
```

Comment: this is ES6, if you are using the latest chrome or firefox it will work.

Comment: I have removed the es6

Comment: It's working now, but it returns the array elements without the selected user input....

Comment: Say, the user selects 456....i want to return 5...would that be possible?

Comment: so you want to return **odd** numbers that are not in your `evenNumbers` array? or is it just all even numbers? what should happen if the user provides an even number? how do you determine double digit numbers eg, 24 could be 24 or 2, 4.

Comment: If a user provides an even number, nothing returns.. I'm using it improve my javascript skills.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
 var userInput = prompt("Please provide an even number!","");


if(userInput%2 ==0){
 document.write('<span style="color:green">That`s correct!</span>');
}else{
 document.write('<span style="color:blue">'+userInput+'</spam=n><span style="color:red"> isn`t a even number!');
}

//-->
</script>
```